# Best Way to Transfer Data to and from a MySQL Database

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please. For a while now I've been working on the Javascript and HTML elements of the Google Maps V3 api. I now want to look at how I'm going to transfer the data to and from MySQL database.

I've read quite a lot of documentation on the Internet on the various methods of transferring this information but I'm not too sure of the best route to take.

I just wondered whether it would be possible that someone with a lot more experience than I could perhaps give me a bit of advice and direction please on the best way to transfer this data.

Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: Are the MySQL databases on one server or different server? Or you want to store Google Maps data in MySQL database? Your question is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a fairly broad question, but mostly dependent on your implementation.  Are you already interfacing with the API using a server side language, or just all with Javascript?  If everything is being done on the client side, then you would want to consider some sort of AJAX/form functionality to get the data from the client to a server side script.  If you are doing any of this on the server side, then you can cut out the AJAX middle man and run SQL commands via PHP or whatnot as you are interfacing with the API.

Comment: Both, many thanks for your replies and apologies if I wasn't as clear as I should have been. The database will store everything that the user keys in on a series of HTML dynamic forms, including all marker information i.e. Address, Lat & Lng co-ordinates. The database obviously has a number of tables but it is being hosted on one server. As it stands at the moment everything is being run through Javascript, so from the limited knowledge I have, and apologies if I've got this wrong, it's a question of needing something between the Javascript and database? Many thanks and regards

Comment: so based on that, when a user inputs data, you want to save that, and then have that information passed along to the API?  Sounds like you want to setup an AJAX function to pass the input data to a server side script so that you can take those values and store them in a meaningful way in your database.  This could happen simultaneously in the background as the values are submitted to the API.

Comment: Hi, yes. Basically all of the screens, albeit with different elements of data will take what a user enters into the relevant fields on the form or may click on the map, and it's this that I would like to be saved and then retrieved at a later date either by the user logging back into the application or revisiting the page. Many thanks.

Comment: I would start looking up how to submit data via forms to a server-side language, like PHP, and then put that into a database.  The trick is the side-by-side integration with the code you are probably using from Google Maps documentation, but the basic of form subition, or data submission via AJAX, will be fundamental and foundational to achieving your desired outcome.  I would review some tutorials on that subject first (like at w3schools.com) and the post some code with your attempts at integrating it.

Comment: Some basic tests just for proof of concept, or a test app on the side might be a good start.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and suggestions and how I should proceed, they're greatly appreciated. So if I've got this right, and apologies if I haven't, but am I right to say that PHP cannot take any of the Google Api information and put this into the database? Regards

Comment: no, it can.  you just have to send the data from the client to the server via AJAX or through a (simultaneous/secondary) form submission.

Comment: Ok, so does the flow go like this? PHP to AJAX to Google Maps? Apologies for the all the questions, this is something that's very new to me. Kind regards

Comment: like I said, you should do some research on submitting form to a server side script, or how to use AJAX.  You pretty much have it backwards.  Example: user submits a form for google maps.  Info is captured and an AJAX request is made to a server side script you make so that PHP can take the data and put it into your DB.  At the same time, you also still have to let the Google maps form fo it's own thing.  Like I said, learn how to do the basics first.

Comment: Ok, many thanks for your time and trouble. I'll start to research these areas. Kind regards.

Comment: if my answers helped you, you may want to consider accepting my answer(s) ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend [MySQl Dump](http://www.roseindia.net/mysql/mysql_backup_restore.shtml). Its fairly simple and there is plenty of documentation on how to do it.

Comment: that seems more like for backup/restore of a database though.

Comment: It sounds to me as if that is what he wants to do. It generates a sql scrip that you can just pull the tables and data you want from. I agree if he wanted certain bits of certain tables there are probably better ways however it seems he wants full tables full of data moving over.

Comment: @thescientist from the further comments it seems you were right he dosent want a backup :)